# Prolog predicate for declaring one object is larger than the other?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write some simple Prolog code that compares objects and lets us know that one object is larger than the other. For instance,

```
larger(star, gasgiant).
larger(gasgiant, rockyplanet).
larger(rockyplanet, moon).
```

The first item listed is larger than the second item listed. This is the relation I was thinking of using to define this:

`larger(X, Y) :- X > Y.`

Is this the correct way to define this relation?

Comment: I don't get your question, why define `larger(X, Y) :- X > Y.` since you have defined already the larger facts above ? `larger(X, Y) :- X > Y.` would be useful only if you want it to work with numbers.

Comment: @coder how could I define that one object is greater than the other? would saying `larger(star, gasgiant)` be enough?

Comment: Yes, you're defining a relation between e.g `star` and `gasgiant` with the convention that first is bigger, same holds for numbers, what does it means that 5>4, it could be written >(5,4) as an prefix operator, same folds for your `larger/2` definition.

Comment: That's why larger(star, gasgiant). is called a fact. It's right there already, you do NOT need to invoke any further knowledge: "Here is the graph node called `star`, here is the graph node called `gasgiant` and here is a link going from `star` to `gasgiant` labeled `larger`." Done! –

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to add the transitive closure, which could be done as follows: `:- table larger/2. larger(X, Y) :- larger(X, Z), larger(Z, Y).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to define this relation?

it can be defined so:

```
larger(X,Y):- compare(>, X, Y).
```

or, simply

```
larger(X,Y):- X @> Y.
```

[Have a look at SWI Prolog docs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compare/3)